# nginx how to do if not regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have as below in nginx but it doesn't do what I intend:

```
location / {
  if ($host !~* blah.blah.com) {
    return 307 https://$host/$request?uri;
  }
}
```

I basically need to do a 307 when $host doesn't match blah.blah.com in regex or it could really just be a plain string. I tried putting them in double quotes or /.../ but nothing seems to work. How do I specify this in nginx's location block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, you do not need to use a *regular expression* to match a single string. You can use the `=` and `!=` operators with the `if` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.

For example:

```
if ($host != foo.example.com) { ... }
```

---

The correct *regular expression* for the above requires two anchors (`^` and `$`) and an escape for the `.` which would otherwise represent any character.

For example:

```
if ($host !~* ^foo\.example\.com$) { ... }
```

The use of quotes is optional, unless the string contains reserved characters (such as `{` and `}`).

See [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html) for more on regular expressions.